# Why can't I have ruby code and comments in Embedded Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following embedded ruby in an html.erb file:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
```

When I add a comment to the embedded ruby like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages'  #shared/error_messages is a file in shared directory %>
```

An error is thrown by the app.  Am I adding the comment incorrectly?

Comment: Will you please edit your question with more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERB has 2 kinds of tags:

1. `<% ruby_code_here %>` (*scriptlet*)
2. `<%= ruby_code_that_gets_output_as_string_here %>` (*expression*)

To my knowledge, there is no way to embed a pure Ruby comment directly inside the expression. You **can** put pure Ruby comments into a scriptlet.

So, for example,

```
<%= link_to "Some path", some_path # your comment %>
```

will crash and burn and **NOT** work.

On the other hand,

```
<% my_link = link_to "Some path", some_path # your comment %>
<%= my_link %>
```

will work just fine.

So, the bottom line is, as long as you are not inside an expression - you can comment away as much as you like.

Answer (score 2):

That is not supported. The correct syntax for a comment in Erb is

```
<%# shared/error_messages is a file in shared directory %>
```

Comment: Is there any way to add an erb comment in a line of erb that also has ruby, like my example above?  Or do they have to be on separate lines?

Comment: In one line: `<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %> <%#shared/error_messages is a file in shared directory %>`